# Get records which do not start with an alphabetical character in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to get a list of records that do not start with an alphabetical character, i.e. which either starts with a numerical character or any special character.

Whats the simple LINQ query to get this list?

Comment: By LINQ to do you actually mean LinqToSQL? Because a lot of the solutions listed here will probably not be translatable to SQL.

Comment: i got to say that, its for Linq to sql.

Comment: @Dan Diplo - what would be the difference? would the linq not be the same i.e. where !char.IsLetter(n.ToCharArray().First())

Comment: The LINQ expression tree has to be translatable to an actual SQL statement. It's very difficult to express many C# expressions as actual SQL - try and imagine what the SQL query would look like for (n.ToCharArray().First()). I'm afraid it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Dan Diplo, As you said, it throws the error "Method 'Boolean IsLetter(Char)' has no supported translation to SQL." when trying with the below answers

Comment: @Dan Diplo - ah well, the answers were correct at the time of going to press

Comment: @Prasad - updated answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<string> Entries = new List<string>();
Entries.Add("foo");
Entries.Add("bar");
Entries.Add("@foo");
Entries.Add("1bar");

var NonAlphas = (from n in Entries
where !char.IsLetter(n.ToCharArray().First())
select n);
```

For Linq-to-sql you could hydrate your retrieval from the database by by enumerating the query (call ToList). From that point on, your operations will be against in-memory objects and those operations will not be translated into SQL.

```
List<string> Entries = dbContext.Entry.Where(n => n.EntryName).ToList();
var NonAlphas = Entries.Where(n => !char.IsLetter(n.First()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("first");
lst.Add("second");
lst.Add("third");
lst.Add("2abc");

var result = from i in lst where !char.IsLetter(i[0]) select i; 
List<string> output = result.ToList();
```

Edit: I realized that using Regex here was overkill and my solution wasn't perfect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] x = new string[3];
x[0] = "avb";
x[1] = "31df";
x[2] = "%dfg";     

var linq = from s in x where !char.IsLetter(s.ToString().First()) select s;
List<string> simplelist = new List<string>(linq);
/* in simple list you have only "31df" & "dfg" */
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that you don't need to convert the string to a chararray to use linq on it.

The more consise version would be:

```
var list = new List<string> {"first","third","second","2abc"};

var result = list.Where(word => !char.IsLetter(word.First()));
```